# How to structure NoSQL data when there are many relations between entities?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm setting up a new structure for a NoSQL database with Google Firestore and I'm struggling with finding the perfect structure what will allow me to:

1. Keep the number of calls to the database low
2. Have a flexible structure that will allow me to edit the way my data is organised in the future. Add more fields, add more relations between collections/docs
3. Keep the consistency of data while keeping the number of automatic triggered updates from Firestore low.

This is my current "schema":

[image: part1]
[image: part2]

Right now, we need to keep this relations:

1. A SPOT belongs to a CITY. 1 - many
2. A CITY belongs to a Region. 1 - many
3. A USER can save a SPOT. many - many
4. A USER can save a CITY. many - many
5. A USER can save a REGION. many - many

These are so far but I want to keep this as flexible as possible. Now I'm storing in each entity a small info about the other entity it has a relation with. E.g. In the CITIES I also keep the id, pic, title, description of the spots that are in that city. But that comes with the drawback of needing to update every information about the city, everywhere, when we need to change some info about a city.

Also, a user needs to have the ability to save spots, cities, region. But if there are thousands of users, each with thousands of saved cities/spots/regions, changing any info about a city/spot/region would mean an update in thousand of places. This is why I decided to only keep the id of the region/city/spot for each user. But I feel I'm not doing it right because it's a different model from what I used for keeping the relations between users - cities - spots.

So my questions are:

1. What is the best way to structure this kind of data with the restrictions above mentioned. What other suggestions do you have for organizing a database like this.
2. Is it a good practice keeping a small amount of data about other entities linked to the current one? Or keeping only the ID is a better solution. Keep in mind that storing only the ID's would require making multiple queries in order to retrieve data.
3. Is it bad practice for not keeping a consistency in structure? In one place using only ID's for the relation and in other places keeping ID + other data.
4. Is there a design pattern for something like this? Is there a way to automatically create "relations" between data (excluding SQL) and have the consistency updates automatically be created?

Comment: This is a very big and a bit vague question. My first concern/question is if you are storing references to other documents then why this statement *changing any info about a city/spot/region would mean an update in thousand of places*. That's the whole idea of storing a reference (the documentId) so if you change info of a document, it's one change in instead of 1000. Also, please stick to one specific question per question - asking a bunch makes it impossibe to answer due to length.

Comment: Thank you. There's the USERS entity where I only store the ID's (reference) but that means that when I do the query I do 2 queries. One for getting the ID and one for getting the actual data.

Comment: Not sure that's very clear; here's an example. Suppose you have a list of users showing in the UI and want to know what city a particular user is in. Since you are displaying a list of users then you already know their user id so you wouldn't have to query for it. Similarly, if I am the user and want to display which spots I have saved, since I am the user, I will know my user id and can simply query the spots for my user id.

Comment: On the other hand, on the CITIES entity I also keep some info about the SPOTS in that city so that when I need to display all the spots for a specific city I only make one query because I only need picture, title, description. Only when I access a specific spot I need the whole data about that spot.